# Sails.js return generated API in a root object

Tags: json, rest, ember.js, sails.js

I'm trying to build a simple API using sails.js in accordance to the json:api [format](http://jsonapi.org/format/). This is so I can use it with Ember.js without having to modify the adapter.

I have used the blueprint generator in sails, like so:

```
sails generate api posts
```

But the base resource at `http://127.0.0.1:1337/posts` gives a response as such:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "2014-11-08T14:45:23.328Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-11-08T14:45:23.328Z",
    "title": "Example post",
    "body": "This is a test"
  }
]
```

But obviously I want a base object so I get a response something like this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2014-11-08T14:45:23.328Z",
      "updatedAt": "2014-11-08T14:45:23.328Z",
      "title": "Example post",
      "body": "This is a test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas how I can do this in Ember.js?

**Edit:** I'm using Ember Data for the data store and adapter.

Comment: Ember doesn't care if you return a root object or not, are you referring to Ember Data?  Ember and Ember Data are two different products.

Comment: @Kingpin2k I'm using ember data as it's the most developed library for data persistence. Should have made it clearer in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking around I haven't found a specific answer to my question, but this is how I figured it out.

Looking into the Sails.js blueprints it generates a responses directory for the API. In here there is an `ok.js` file which handles the serving of data for a 200 response.

File: `api/responses/ok.js`.

There are several return lines like the following:

```
return res.jsonx(data);
```

As I only have one resource in my API I changed the code to:

```
return res.jsonx({ "posts": data });
```

This wraps the data in the root object which ember data expects by default.